# How to leave only characters in field

Tags: r, string, gsub

Im fairly new to the R language.

I have a field as a factor with the code and name of the employee.

What line of command will remove the code and only leave the Name of the Emp from the PastActivity table.

Name

```
C4241463 - Hadya, Susan

C4315634 - Sarah, S
```

Anticipated Result

```
Hadya, Susan

Sarah, S
```

Ive tried using the sub command to remove the string upto the point of the space after the hyphen but still no luck

```
gsub("C[0-9]\\- ", "", PastActivity$Name)
```

Comment: There should be a duplicate for this: `gsub(".* - ", "", "C4241463 - Hadya, Susan")`. Remove everything `.*` before `-`. In you original code you have to add `+` (`gsub("C[0-9]+ - ", "", "C4241463 - Hadya, Susan")`)

Comment: @PoGibas is correct,  Note, you were very close in your own answer.  I.e. try modifying your gsub to be

`gsub("C[0-9]+ - ", "", PastActivity$Name)` and it will work for you

Answer (score 1):

Or using stringr you can use

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("C4241463 - Hadya, Susan", "C4315634 - Sarah, S")
str_trim(str_split(x, "-", simplify = TRUE)[,2])
```

Here str_split is splitting in "-", and then str_trim is trimming the white space

Comment: Why but split on `" - "` and do away with the white space directly?